# Split a spark dataframe column at , and not at \,

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame which contains comma (,) separated values and implements and escape character “,” how do I split that values while not splitting at escape character?

Comment: See quote and escape in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I do not have a csv file, instead I have values separate by commas in a column of dataframe like value1,value2,value3,value4,\donot split,value5,value6. So I donot need to split at ,\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the escaped comma using a negative lookbehind regex:

```py
df.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|value1,value2,value3,value4\,donot split,value5,value6|
+------------------------------------------------------+

df.select(F.split(F.col('value'), "(?<!\\\\),")).show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|split(value, (?<!\\),, -1)                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|[value1, value2, value3, value4\,donot split, value5, value6]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```